# Does disliking or ignoring a YouTube video more impactfully deprecate it?

Tags: youtube

Supposing that I—-supreme arbiter of the good and the bad—-think that a certain YouTube video is irrelevant clickbait.

Am I more likely to deprecate its appearance by disliking it, or ignoring it?

Comment: Hi and welcome. May I clarify something here? You are not asking us to guess which option you might choose, are you? Rather you're asking "which option is the more effective if the intention is to 'depreciate' the video"? Which, presumably, is an issue impacting on the YouTube algorithms.

Comment: Right. As in Am I more likely to get home faster by taking the bus or the subway?